# FFmpeg freezes the computer halfway through encoding

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, freeze, zorin

This is the command I am using:

`for i in *.mp4; do ffmpeg -i "$i" -map_metadata -1 -c:v libvpx-vp9 -c:a libopus -crf 19 "${i%.*}.webm"; done`

It was running fine for a while, it got about 75% through the first file last time I ran it.
But then it hard freezes, the whole system was locked up.
The only way I could reset was to hold down the power button.

Specs of computer:

i5-3330s
8GB RAM
256GB SSD
Running Latest Zorin OS Lite (reinstalled yesterday, so nothing on it except what is preinstalled and FFmpeg)

I ran prime95 for half an hour and it didn't crash there, and the CPU temps never went over 55 degrees, so I don't think it's an overheating issue.

FFmpeg didn't really "crashed", so there is no output error, it just completely froze.

I checked the log files and couldn't see anything out of the ordinary apart from in the syslog - there was what I think is an auto firmware update around the same time it froze.
Not sure if that could have caused it.